# connect with liaison LAPI in php

Tags: galileo

I want to connect with liaison LAPI (Liaison sita gabriel, Airline ticketing system ) to sita gds but don't exist any document or manual and I don't know how work it.

Just there is  LAPI.ocx in installed directory of Liaison.